# Strapi backend and query restrictions

Tags: backend, strapi

I'm currently using Strapi as backend for online shop, and faced with such problems: by default Strapi return all data in GET queries, for example `http://host.com/users` will return all users' fields including `privateMessages`, `orders`, `favoritedProducts`, but this data should be private. How do I restrict this, so every user can get only own private data?

Also Strapi has strange permission settings, if I allow to update `User` model, that basically means, the other users can perform PUT queries and edit other users' data, but if I restrict updating `User` model, then user can't update own data

Answer (score 0):

To did it you will have to add custom logic based on info you have in `ctx.state.user`

documentation here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/authentication.html#user-object-in-strapi-context

You can create a policy and apply it yo the route you want or update your controller code to restrict the access.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do this and I have a problem. How do I get the requested resource? I can easy get user's id from ctx.state.user but I need to compare it to the resource owner. I guess for now I could do something stupid like making a http request with axios or something but I'm sure there is a way to do it in strapi.

Comment: You will have to `findOne` the entry you want to fetch (before send it) and check if the user relation match with the user you are logged in. If it doesn't match, you have to send an error instead of sending  the data. Or before to execute an update.